# R blogdown: How to link to another blog from within a blog

Tags: r, blogdown

I am having trouble linking to another blog post when using blogdown.

I believe I have tried the following, in addition to a number of other variants:

- ../../../../my_other_file.html
- blog/my_other_file.html
- /blog/my_other_file.html

To date, with no success...

In setting up, I pretty much followed the instructions by [Alison Presmanes Hill](https://alison.rbind.io/post/up-and-running-with-blogdown/)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it ...

- /blog/2018/10/15/2018-10-15-rest_of_blog_name

Note there is no .html at the end.

This is also as specified in the config.toml file:

```
[Permalinks]
    blog = "/blog/:year/:month/:day/:filename/"
```